# Chrome app fails to open usb device

Tags: google-chrome, usb, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to connect to a smartcard reader form a chrome app using [chrome.usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb). The permissions in the manifest are set properly and `lsusb` recognizes the device.

`chrome.usb.getDevices` detects the device but when I try to open it using `chrome.usb.openDevice` I get "Failed to open device". I've tried it on both windows 7 with chrome 43 and ubuntu with chrome 42 and got the same result. I've also installed chrome [device-info sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/usb/device-info) and got the same message.

Is there anything I should be looking at on the device itself? Could it be related to permissions?

Comment: Windows users may give a try at http://zadig.akeo.ie/ here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=302278

Comment: Funny, I'm trying to do this same thing. Is hacking the driver using Zadig the only way? ***Why** does* Chrome fail to open the device on Windows? Is this another Microsoft Mystery™?

Comment: I used the [USB Device Info](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/usb-device-info/igkmggljimacfdfalpeelenjeicmfnll) app and found that out of the 11 devices Chrome can list, 10 devices "Failed to open" (including an ACS Smartcard Reader) and the 1 device that opened was my wired optical mouse...

Answer (score 2):

First you need to figure out the vendor and product IDs for your device. If you run `lsusb` it will list the devices on your system in a format like this:

```
~$ lsusb

Bus {Bus number} Device {device id}: ID {vendorid in hexa}:{product id in hexa} Manufacturer Product
```

Once you know this information you can create a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` with the name `{deviceid}.rules`. Replace `{deviceid}` with the value obtained from the output up there.

The content should be the following:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="vendorid", ATTR{idProduct}=="productid", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`

Replace `vendorid` and `productid` with corresponding hexadecimal values obtained by running the command above.

Answer (score 1):

News? I found in `chrome://device-log/` the message :

> usb_device_impl.cc:259 Failed to open device: Access denied (insufficient permissions)

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was `Failed to open '/dev/hidraw1': FILE_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, I then did `chmod 777 /dev/hidraw1`, and it finally worked!